# Closing a Popup on a UserControl on BackKeyPress

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I have a project in windows phone 8.1 silverlight in which I have a User Control which is displayed on a click event on a button from the main page. And that user control has a button. upon clicking that button a popup appears this popup is also a UserControl.
Now I want to close this Popup on BackKeypress. As UserControl cannot have the BackkeyPress event, its difficult to that. So  is it possible and if yes how?

Please let me know..

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and its working like this
I added  this code in MainPage.xaml.cs in OnBackkeyPress()

```
if(usercontrol1.Visibility==Visibility.Visible && usercontrol.popup_usercontrol2.IsOpen)
{
     UC_UserProfile.pop_upAddVehicles.IsOpen = false;
     e.cancel=true;
}
```

where usercontrol1 is the control coming on click of button on mainpage and popup_usercontrol2 is the popup coming on click of buttom on usercontrol1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the key up or key down event of your user control and detect the key like this:

```
private void usercontrol1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    If (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: ok..I am Trying it but there is no property like KeyCode instead there is PlatformkeyCode so are they same?

Comment: There should be. Take a look at this:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/909/how-to-handle-keycode-events-in-windows-phone-88-110.aspx

Comment: It looks like PlatformKeyCode will also work:https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.platformkeycode(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Ok..i'll try according to above link.

Comment: No its not working. Does this Keys.Back refers to hardware back button

Comment: Yes, Keys.Back is the backspace key.

Comment: I want it on hardware back button. On event BackKeyPress.